# PHP > MySQL Floating point separator localisation issue

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, locale, decimal-point

I've seen a few questions on people trying to get MySQL to use ',' as the floating point separator - what I'm trying to do is **stop** PHP from using it on a website running under the 'nl_NL' locale.

So in the code PHP is writing an SQL query ending like:

```
" ... HAVING `relevance` >= {$fFloatingPointNumber}";
```

The problem is, because PHP's locale is running as 'nl_NL' when it converts that floating point number to a string it's using ',' as the separator (e.g. 1,5).

What I'm doing to prevent this currently is:

```
" ... HAVING `relevance` >= " . number_format($fFloatingPointNumber, 2, '.', '');
```

Is there a better way of doing this - or is this my best bet?

Comment: Could you not create some sort of wrapper for database queries that temporarily changes the locale to one which uses the "." separator?  I don;t know if this would be an acceptable solution, I've never worked with other locales for my PHP/MySQL stuff. Alterbnatively possibly do all your database stuff then switch to the proper locale later when you want to output the data for the user.

Comment: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/php-floats-localization-and-landmines  This might help (the last two comments) although I'm not really sure.

Comment: It's already in a wrapper - the problem with that is that I'd have to juggle the locale every time the PHP builds a query rather than in the abstract base class because there's no guarantee that there won't be application code which _should_ be using `nl_NL` occurring between when the database wrapper in constructed and destructed.

Comment: From the limited searching I've done I have not found a solution, just the somewhat annoying one I mentioned above with switching locale for every query.

Comment: I have posted an updated answer which I think may work and be your best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

I will post my answer in case it is the only solution apart from @Pete one.

I would suggest switching the locale to GB or some other period separated float/double locale before each query then switching back to the correct locale after.  I can not think of any other way around this.

**Solution 2 (Best Bet)**

You could always use the `number_format` method as follows

```
$stringversion = number_format($theFloat, 2, ".","");
```

Pretty sure this would work, the documentation is here http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: hehe - if you read my question fully, you'll see that's exactly what I'm doing atm ... I was wondering if there was a "neater" way :)

Comment: @CD001 haha I swear I read it differently.  I think you probably have the better solution to be quite honest.  I will keep looking but I prefer the number format rather than locale change.  Imagine if for example GB decided to change their decimal separator to a "," instead, your method would not have a problem, the switching locale though would.

Comment: well - I think general consensus then is that `number_format` is probably the best way to go, so I'll accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this or something similar? Credit to Ludovico Grossi

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_GB'); //overwrite the decimal separator
?>
```

Comment: still a problem for output though since when the user gets their page displayed they will now see the british separator.

Comment: @JonTaylor - You're right Jon. And your comment above seems to be the only answer if mine isn't acceptable. Or using number_format all the time... which amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Especially since the application needs to output UK (£x.xx), Irish (€x.xx) and Dutch (€ x,xx) prices depending on the locale (done using NumberFormatter and the ICU decimal format) - it's when building SQL queries the I need a floating point number represented in the SQL standard of x.x - I'm not sure whether using something like `mysqli_stmt::prepare` would help...

Comment: I made a site in Dutch a few years ago and I ended up using number_format (wrapped in a function). It was a kludge really, but being UK-based the x.x format is my starting point.